# Dynamicly populate Contact form 7 input fields with current user info when logged in in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form, contact-form-7

I've been trying to figure out how to populate input fields in contact forms on my Wordpress website. I've tried using a plugin called Contact Form 7 dynamic text extension, and tried a pretty simple IF statement with PHP. But i just can't seem to get this to work.

With the plugin, i can only get half of the arguments to work in the shortcode, even then the form doesn't properly validate.

Using PHP as a placeholder="" outputs the code instead of the contents of the variable. for example "$current_user->user_firstname"

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I need to do the same thing, but I can not.

Answer (score 4):

You can install this plugin

[Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)

Dynamic text and dynamic hidden fields are available using it.
And you can use the following code to grab the current user info into your field.

```
[dynamictext dynamicname "CF7_get_current_user"]
```

Or as mentioned in the answer above:

```
[dynamictext your-email "CF7_get_current_user key='user_email' "]
```

Note also that you can use `dynamichidden` for hidden fields like the following

```
[dynamichidden your-email "CF7_get_current_user key='user_email' "]
```

**PS: I faced an issue with required hidden fields when I tried to use this `dynamichidden*`, the shortcode appears on my website as a plain text.**

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, i wasn't using the shortcode correctly.
These are the shortcodes i've used in with Contact Form 7 Dynamic text extension:

```
    Naam* <br />
     [dynamictext* your-name 'CF7_get_current_user']
    Email*
     [dynamictext* your-email "CF7_get_current_user key='user_email' "]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an PHP array `$gigs`, and you want to display it as a drop down list in your form like this:

```
<label>
  <strong>Choose your gig</strong>
  [select upcoming-gigs data:gigs]
</label>
[submit]
```

Simply add this to your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args) {
  if (in_array('gigs', $options)){
    $gigs = array(
      "MAY 07 - NEW ORLEANS, LA",
      "MAY 09 - AUSTIN, TX",
      "MAY 12 - HOUSTON, TX"
    );
    return $gigs;
  }
  return $n;
}, 10, 3);
```

Now your drop down field should look like this:
[image: dynamic dropdown with Contact Form 7]

Source: https://bdwm.be/dynamically-populate-a-contact-form-7-dropdown-list-or-any-other-input-field/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before. Instead of using the PHP code as a placeholder. Use jQuery, for example:

```
$firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;

<script>

$("input").val("<?php echo $firstname; ?>")

</script>
```

Comment: When i use <?php $firstname = $current_user->user_firstname; ?>
I'm getting "$firstname = $current_user->user_firstname; ?>" as output.

And when i try to output it directly, the output is empty:
<script>

$("input").val("<?php echo $current_user->user_firstname ?>")

</script>

Comment: Check if you are doing it like this:
`<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      $firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;

?>` Also make sure that the firstname field is not empty and that you run the jQuery script once the document is ready.

Comment: The line of PHP seems to be working fine, as long as i dont put an Enter in the code. Bit weird, but i can live with that.

I've set up the input field like so with Contact Form 7:  [text* your-name class:your-name]

And trying to set the fields placeholder with jQuery now like so:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".your-name").val("Placeholder");
});
</script>

I'm not getting any error's or weird text, but the placeholder is also not being set.