# Populate Contact Form 7 field based on other field value

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to populate a field or two based on the value of another (to save on data entry). The form is based on WordPress, using the 'Contact Form 7' plugin.

So if text field 1 has the value "2 Years" I'd like it to populate another field with the text "Twenty Four Months".

I have the Dynamic Text Field plugin installed, which I know will accommodate custom short codes, but I'm not that clued up on this. I'm happy to use Javascript of JQuery to achieve the goal.

Has anyone tried and accomplished the above before?

Many thanks,
Simon

Comment: This may help, [look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406149/dynamicly-populate-contact-form-7-input-fields-with-current-user-info-when-logge?rq=1)

Answer (score -2):

You can try Plugin "[Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) "

Comment: That plugin only allows you to (conditionally) show or hide a group of fields. It does not have features for changing field values.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Yes like Sally says, the plugin suggested only shows/hides fields based on other fields ticked etc. and it also submits all data regardless of whether or not it was showing or hidden. It's more for display/usability than the back-end.