# Contact Form 7 - how to add several number fields dynamically

Tags: contact-form-7

I am currently working on a web project where users should be able to have a list of brochures (list comes from custom post type) and enter the amount they would like to order individually for each of them via a simple contact form. My idea was to generate a dynamic list of number fields with the 'wpcf7_form_tag_data_option' hook like in this article:

[Dynamicly populate Contact form 7 input fields with current user info when logged in in Wordpress website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406149/dynamicly-populate-contact-form-7-input-fields-with-current-user-info-when-logge/62503322#62503322)

So if i am using the select or checkbox field type within contact form 7:

```
[select anzahlKataloge data:brochures]
```

or

```
[checkbox anzahlKataloge data:brochures]
```

and functions.php:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args) {
    if (in_array('brochures', $options)){
        $query = new WP_Query(
            array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => '100', 'post_type' => 'prospekte')
        );

        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();

        $brochures[] = $title;

        endwhile;

        return $brochures;
    }
    return $n;
}, 10, 3);
```

It generates the select or checkbox list just fine but i would actually need it to work with the number field type:

```
[number anzahlKataloge data:brochures]
```

or with text type:

```
[text anzahlKataloge data:brochures]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rafael

Comment: I would make my own form tag `wpcf7_add_form_tag` rather than filtering `wpcf7_form_tag_data_option`

Comment: Good advice thanks will do

Comment: If you need help with that... you can update this question

Comment: Implemented now :) thanks again for pointing this out..gotta love wordpress and cf7